# Handling LINQ "Count" queries as IDocumentQuery

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

Horsing around the CosmosDB .NET SDK, I found an intriguing issue.
I wanted to use the SDK LINQ support for the following query:

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE <predicate>
```

Well, immediately after writing the LINQ query, I realized there might be no way to handle such queries as document queries. However, since document queries allow you to capture query metrics and unblock a thread between pages of results, I strongly prefer it. Here's the code:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>.Where(<predicate>).Count()
```

Even though I understand that the result type of Count() isn't IQueryable, is there a way to handle "count" queries as document queries?

Comment: For future reference, inside VS you can view the interface that Cosmos provides for pagination/aggregation operations by looking at at the `DocumentQueryable` class

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is a way to do that.

There is a `CountAsync` extension built into the SDK.

Simply construct your `IQueryable` and use `.CountAsync()` when you are ready to get the count.

Keep in mind however that there will be no metric collection as the result is aggregated in the SDK.

If you really need metrics then you can use the usual `DocumentQuery` created from SQL rather than LINQ and the  `while.HasMoreResults`, `ExecuteNextAsync` logic and capture the metrics from the paginated result, per iteration.

Comment: Thanks, the DocumentQueryable extensions allow the asynchronous run. However, I still need the metrics for all my queries and using string queries is my last resort. I was kind of hoping that any LINQ query would be transformable to a Document query.

Comment: Why don't you do this then: `client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>.Where(<predicate>).AsDocumentQuery()` ?

Comment: Also string queries shouldn't be last resort, unless there a specific reason you don't want them. The LINQ query will be converted into SQL when it runs against CosmosDB anyway. You can simply do `select value count(1) from c where <expression>` and it will be the exact same thing.

Comment: Again, thanks for the comments. Let me address them one by one.
"client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>.Where(<predicate>).AsDocumentQuery()" -> I want a server-side count, not client-side in order to optimize RUs

"The LINQ query will be converted into SQL when it runs against CosmosDB anyway." -> That's pretty obvious, but I want to design a usable repository abstraction for my team. Using LINQ is great since the caller can use expressions to represent filtering, projection etc. If I were to use SQL queries, I would need to manually translate the abstraction into a SQL query.